# Caching null-values

Tags: java

I'm having an argument with my chief architect about caching null-values. His opinion is, that null-values by definition aren't cached.

My problem now is, that there is always a cache-miss and a piece of code is always entered without any need, since the null value is totally fine in my case.

My question: Is there an official definition on this case?

Comment: "Aren't cached" in what context? You haven't given us *nearly* enough information to give you any kind of answer.

Comment: We got some piece of code, that caches some key-value pairs. Underlying is Ehcache (by default Ehcache caches key-values pairs with null-values, we don't). Now I'm in the situation that I have numerous db-accesses that could be avoided if null-values would be stored in our cache.

Comment: Cache implementation are mostly likely very generic. That means you could reuse it anywhere in your application. If your generic cache is designed to take `null` as **not cached**. Then it's not worthy to change the behavior if only one or two of your caches are taking `null` as cached values. However, if you really want to cache the null values as well, you need another implementation(may be extend the original cache) of the cache to cache `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt there is an official document for this case as the answer strongly depends on your usage. For instance imagine you have a web query taking 200 ms to be processed that returns null and that is a valid value. Of course you would cache this to avoid these extra 200 ms everytime you do the query.

I am personally with you on the case. Rules saying **never** do... are rarely without an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Your chief architect tries to be the one who is right, but he isn't:
the NullObjectPattern is used to handle "cached null values"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

In a lot of cases it's a simple and objectoriented solution, to handle the cached information.
Just get the value of the key and call the method. The object knows what to do.
No "ifs", no "oh there is an other list" and "we are slow, because we try to access the resource to know, that there is nothing".

Check out this: they did a lot of work, just to avoid this "null-thing":
http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the point of your cache is to speed up execution and reduced unnecessary function calls.

If adding null values to the cache improves this (i.e. lowers execution time overall), then adding them would make sense. After all, the purpose of a cache is (usually) to speed up either some part of or the entire application, rather than being treated as a key/value store

Of course with anything like this, you should really measure before making any change. E.g. allowing a large number of null cache entries could force out non-null entries, which may turn out to be way costlier to bypass the cache for.

Answer (score -2):

Your chief architect is right. Do what he says. If you are interested in keeping a record of the keys that came in without values, use a different data structure to store these keys rather than Cache these keys with null values. I am not sure if there is official documentation on this but this is a standard practice.